# How to refresh image at before position in viewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, zooming

I use a viewPager has images extend of PinchImageView which provide that zooming image. 
When I have scrolled in position to other position in viewPager, zoomed image kept old state.

PinchImageView library link: https://github.com/boycy815/PinchImageView

How to refresh image at before position in viewPager? I've thinked that use `destroyItem` but didn't find how to do it.

```
private class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        PinchImageView photoView;

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_images, container, false);

            photoView = ViewUtil.findById(view, R.id.photoView);
            photoView.setViewPager(viewPager);

            Image image = allImages.get(position);
            if (image != null) {

              String path = image.getPath();

              if (hasPathControl(path)) {
               setImage();
               loadImage(path, photoView);
            }

            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return allImages.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object obj) {
            return view == (obj);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

            Mylog.i(TAG, " destroyItem position " + position);

            container.removeView((View) object);

        }

        private void loadImage(String path, ImageView imageView) {

            glideRequests.load(path)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .dontTransform()
                    .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                    .transition(withCrossFade())
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }
```

Moving to the other position:

Must be:[image: Must be]

Existing:  [image: Actually]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this is to update/refresh the view in the `ViewPager` when it is the current position.

From the java doc of the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/core-ui/src/main/java/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.java) of `PagerAdapter`

> PagerAdapter supports data set changes. Data set changes must occur on the main thread and must end with a call to {@link #notifyDataSetChanged()} similar to AdapterView adapters derived from {@link android.widget.BaseAdapter}. A data set change may involve pages being added, removed, or changing position. The ViewPager will keep the current page active provided the adapter implements the method {@link #getItemPosition(Object)}.

Add a `OnPageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager`. And on `onPageSelected` call the `notifyDataSetChanged` on your `PagerAdapter`.

This should call the `getItemPosition` of the `PagerAdapter`. Then add this to your `PagerAdapter`:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

You should get the updated view at that position.